# How to remove "Help us keep magento healthy" in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, layout, template, footer, magento-2.1

Can anybody tell me where they moved this?

Changed the footer.phtml in

```
/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html
```

But it is still being shown, so it must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in two places:

- in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml` as you said
- but also in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/bugreport.phtml`

Regarding the second one you can remove the entire block with the following layout code:

```
<referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

For `2.4` you can hide this in admin.

> Admin > Content > Design > Konfiguration > "Select theme" > Footer >
> "Display Report Bugs Link (Yes/No)"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the bug report links by adding layout code

```
<referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />
```

In app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

NOTE: Location of your theme files may vary depending on the way Magento was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct. This will crash the search bar and the mini cart. The default.xml file needs to be in the following path:

/app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/override/base

you need override/base

Answer (score -1):

In app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml