# Magento 2.1 Structure Questions

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, footer

I want to remove the Keep Magento Healthy from my Footer. I followed the instructions in this question but am confused as to how to lay it out in my custom theme. [How to remove "Help us keep magento healthy" in Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125310/how-to-remove-help-us-keep-magento-healthy-in-magento-2-1)

I have copied what is inside the the module-theme frontend folder from vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/ into my app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme

So currently inside of my Theme folder it looks a bit like this:
Magento_Theme
--layout 
--templates 
--html 
----footer.phtlm 
----bugreport.phtml
--web
--layouts.xml
etc
i18n
media
web
--css
----source

To the layout.xml files I added in the suggested to code remove the bug block

from the footer.phtml file I removed:
bug tracking link

I cleared the cache and nothing changed.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?
Also, on the file structure in the vendor folder you have the module_files
and then you have the front end files with the css files inside. Am I correct in putting the layout.xml files into the app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme or do the module-files all go into the app/code folder?

My apologies for these really basic questions. I cannot wait I know enough that this will look like a silly question to me! Thank you for all your help.

A novice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to reproduce the folder structure for the files you want to extend, so if you want the change the default.xml layout file, originally in `module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`, you want to create the following file: `app/design/frontend/YourVendorName/YourThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

To remove the link, you actually have to either edit `html/bugreport.phtml` or remove that block altogether, I don't know where `html/footer.phtml` is used, but it's not in the main pages.

The prefered way is to remove the block via layout files. If you search for "Help Us Keep Magento Healthy" with you IDE, you'll find that the block is defined in `default.xml` and is called `report.bugs`.

So create your `default.xml` file like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

The `<referenceBlock>` element means "target that block" and the rest is self-descriptive.

Don't forget to enable your theme and clearing your cache to see the change.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as valid, then? It'll help future newcomers. :)

Comment: I'm on 2.2.2 and this didn't work for me.